# Whiptail menus not responding to key presses or mouse clicks - displays ```^[[B``` when I press down arrow

Tags: command-line, bash, ssh, keys, tui

I have created an installer bash script for setting up a DigiByte full node via the linux command line. It works fine in Raspberry Pi OS lite 64-bit on the Pi 4, but if I install Ubuntu Server 64-bit LTS on the Pi (arm64) I am getting intermittent issues with the whiptail dialog boxes not working. When it reaches a menu I am unable to navigate or proceed - pressing return or the arrow keys prints strange characters to the screen. Scrolling with my trackpad also spits out strange characters. Strangely, if I Ctrl-C out of it, and then manually run the same whiptail menu command directly from the command line it works fine.

I have tested the issue over SSH from both Mac (iTerm 2) and Win10 (Putty) and get the same issue on both systems. However, I also have experienced the odd situation where it seems to suddenly work normally - the problem seems intermittent. That said I have recently encountered it again and no amount of rebooting or trying different terminals seems to solves it. I should also add that I have just tried it with Ubuntu Server 64-bit on a PC laptop (x86) and it works fine, and I can navigate with the keyboard without issue.

Can anyone explain what is likely causing the issue, and how to solve it?

[image: Whiptail menu not responding to key presses]

Comment: Set Line discipline more conformant (stty sane)

Comment: Or coding error in your script?

Comment: I have since discovered that this is a known bug in recent versions of Ubuntu. It occurs when piping a script through bash.